# If the observer is changed will the time too be changed as well?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames

So I was solving a problem yesterday (school level) the question stated:

> "A ball is dropped from a balloon going up at the speed of $7 \ m/s$.If the balloon was at height $60 \ m$ at the time of dropping the ball, how long will the ball take in reaching the ground?"

So accordingly,
$u=-7m/s$

$S=60m$

$a=g=9.8m/s^2$

So using **$S=ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$** I got the answer of time as $4.28s$.

But what if I changed the observer and the observer too is in the balloon so with respect to the observer in the balloon the initial velocity of the ball is $0 \ m/s$, which changes the time, so am I correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Think about what the ground is doing in the reference frame of the balloon observer.

Comment: @notovny well the ball will land in the ground, but the as the observer and ball both are in the baloon so shouldn't they be in rest with respect to each other?

Comment: The balloon is moving in the reference frame of the ground, therefore the ground is moving in the reference frame of the balloon.

Comment: @notovny interesting, but be more concise please

Comment: @notovny but what's the role of ground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you like change the frame of reference to the observer in the balloon and this will *not* change the physical result. You will see the ball move in your (upward) direction, stop, and then start moving downward.

If you are in the balloon and release the ball, the ball *initially* moves in your direction with a speed $+7ms^{-1}$, then stops, before it starts to move away from you. At that point, since $$v=u-at$$ then $$0=7-9.8t \\ \rightarrow t=0.71\ s$$ That is, after this time, the ball will then begin to move toward the ground so that it will reach its initial point of release again at $t=0.71+0.71=1.42 \ s$.

At this point, the ball will have an initial velocity of $v=+7\ ms^{-1}$ (note that the sign is now positive and when you calculated it it was negative) and it is at a height of $60\ m$ so $$60=7t+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$ which will give $t=2.86\ s$

The ball will take a total time of $$t=2.86+1.42=4.28\ s$$ which is also consistent with the original answer.

Comment: ```At this point, the ball will have an initial velocity of v=+7 ms−1``` but how? I mean like the ball os moving downwards so shouldn't the velocity be negative?

Comment: Because at the same point the ball is now moving downwards in the same direction as the acceleration $g$.

Comment: But idk why we were taught that the sign of velocity (because of direction) is kinda same as the cartesian plane. (Motion in a straight line)

Comment: ```This problem involves one-dimensional motion in the vertical direction. We use plus and minus signs to indicate direction, with up being positive and down negative.``` "https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/2-7-falling-objects/#:~:text=We%20use%20plus%20and%20minus,downward%2C%20so%20a%20is%20negative."

Comment: Yes, this is also fine, provided you always have consistent directions. For example, if we look at the above, I had $60=7t+\frac{1}{2}gt^2$ but if I had chosen down to be negative then $-60=-7t-4.9t^2$ and I _still_ would have got $t=2.86\ s$. Just remember to always be consistent with what direction you call positive and what you call negative.

Comment: But how could the distance be like negative? Like the direction should be influencing the velocity not the distance if I'm not wrong,As in the case of motion in a straight line.

Comment: If you choose the downward direction to be negative, then moving downward would be moving in the negative direction, correct? Displacement is also a vector. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should still get the same result. Things are different in relativity where different observers measure different times, but Newtonian mechanics has absolute time and everyone measures the same time.

If the observer is on the ball then they observe the ground $60m$ away and getting further at $7 m/s$, but the ground is also accelerating towards the ball at $9.8 m/s^2$. You end up with exactly the same equation (albeit interpreted differently) and exactly the same time. Compare:

- The ball is $60m$ away, going up at $7 m/s$, and accelerating towards the ground at $9.8 m/s^2$.
- The ground is $60m$ away, moving away at $7 m/s$, and accelerating towards the ball at $9.8 m/s^2$.

which should hopefully illustrate that the two calculations are symmetrical.

What if the observer is on the balloon? Then the initial velocity of the ball is $0 m/s$, the ground is $60m$ away + getting more distant at $7 m/s$, and the ball is accelerating at $9.8 m/s^2$ while the ground isn't. You still end up with exactly the same equation, because $u$ is the relative speed between the ball and the ground (the two objects that are colliding). You should get the same time, as expected.